# Theme's dashboard content is displaying in another theme

Tags: magento2.4.1

I have a theme named Solwin. I have applied this theme before and changed it to Magento luma. Dashboard content in Solwin is showing up on homepage even after I selected luma theme. How to disable that? Any ideas

Answer (score 0):

changed it to Magento luma then run two command

1. php bin/magento indexer:reindex
2. php bin/magento cache:clean